# Search with django Haystack

Tags: django, search, elasticsearch, whoosh

I have followed multiple different examples multiple different times, but it seems that I am missing something along the line. --> point short, with both whoosh, or elasticsearch along with haystack, search results to nothing.

model

```
class Note(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(User)
title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
body = models.TextField()
pub_date = models.DateTimeField()

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.title
```

form

```
 class NotesSearchForm(SearchForm):

    def no_query_found(self):
        return self.searchqueryset.all()

    def search(self):
        # First, store the SearchQuerySet received from other processing. (the main work is run internally by Haystack here).
        sqs = super(NotesSearchForm, self).search()

        # if something goes wrong
        if not self.is_valid():
            return self.no_query_found()

        # you can then adjust the search results and ask for instance to order the results by title
        sqs = sqs.order_by(title)

        return sqs
```

Views

```
def search(request):

# we retrieve the query to display it in the template
form = NotesSearchForm(request.GET)

# we call the search method from the NotesSearchForm. Haystack do the work!
results = form.search()

return render(request, 'search.html', {'search_query' : search_query,
                                                    'notes' : results,
                                                })
```

template

```
  <!-- EXTENDS BASE
================================================== -->
{% extends 'base.html' %}
<!-- NAVBAR
================================================== -->
        {% block nav %}
            {% include 'nav1.html' %}
        {% endblock %}
<!-- Marketing messaging and featurettes
================================================== -->
    <!-- Wrap the rest of the page in another container to center all the content. -->
    {% block marketing %}
        <div class="container marketing">
          <!-- START THE FEATURETTES -->
          <hr class="featurette-divider">
          <div class="row featurette">
            <div class="col-md-7">
                <h2>Search</h2>
                <form type="get" action="/search/">
                    <input type="text" name="q">
                    <button type="submit">Search</button>
                </form>
                 <p>Your query "{{ search_query }} has returned {{ notes.count }} result{{ notes|pluralize }}"</p>
                 {% for note in notes %}
                 <h1>{{ note.title }}</h1>
                 <p>
                     {{ note.body }}
                 </p>
                 {% endfor %}
            </div>
          </div>
          <hr class="featurette-divider">
          <!-- /END THE FEATURETTES -->
        </div><!-- /.container -->
    {% endblock %}
```

I know that this is a bit long, but I cant seem to figure out what is going wrong. the search page is working, but when text is searched no result is found.

I want to enter a 'search_text' in the text form and for it to return all instances in which the 'search_text' appears in the documents in the database with a certain amount of tokens before and after as such

| title | user | {number of tokens preceding } 'search_text' {number of tokens following}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason as to why it was not working is that I did not have elasticsearch running on my machin. Therefore, by installing and running elasticsearch server on the machin, I was able to have search results. Instructions can be found here : http://chriskief.com/2014/05/14/django-haystack-and-elasticsearch-part-1/

additionaly pyelasticsearch and elasticsearch is needed to run the search.